# WSo2 API Manager 1.8.0 - JSON parsing issue

Tags: json, api, wso2, uri, wso2-api-manager

I am new to wso2 API Manager, trying to set it up expose my plain HTTP POST back end calls as a REST API. I am sure this is not a new pattern that I am trying to achieve here. The requirement is to convert the JSON data coming in (has array structures) into the HTTP URL query string parameters.

After some research through the documentation and other posts on this forum, decided to go with the script mediator that would parse the JSON data and convert it to a string that can be appended to the endpoint URL. Some how I am not able to achieve this.

I have followed the following post that seems to be very straight forward. As the original poster suggested, I am also not able to use getPayloadJSON() method. Even have trouble using the work around suggested there due to JSON.parse() not working.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848342/getpayloadjson-returning-an-empty-object)

Also, this approach of editing the service bus configuration from source view does not sound like the correct option. Is there another elegant solution to achieve this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get both methods working by using an external script instead of the inline java script. Thanks